# Visual Editor only working for the admin user

Tags: admin, visual-editor, wysiwyg

Any idea why the visual editor would only work on the administrator user. Not even with the administrator role I can get it to work.

I just shows a white box with white type inside it and has none of the wysiwyg buttons.

Thanks in advanced

Edit:
I'm using TinyMCE Advanced and Advanced TinyMCE Config

Comment: any javascript errors in console?

Comment: Actually yes:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/en.js?ver=349-21274
Failed to load: /wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/en.js wp-tinymce.php:33
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js?ver=349-21274
Failed to load: /wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js wp-tinymce.php:33

Comment: Never thought of checking! But how do I go about and fix this?

Comment: Sounds like your WP install is corrupt. I would reload these from the version you're running.

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgraded-to-32-visual-editor-buttons-missing/page/2

this fixed it.

> The Tiny MCE is looking for a file: wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/en.js
>
> I just checked the file and on my installation the file path is this:
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs-en.js
>
> I deleted the 'wp-langs-' part of the file name 'wp-langs-en.js' and I
>   seem to be working again.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept your own answer by clicking on the big green check mark.